# Insert value into sorted linked list in ascending order

Tags: c, linked-list

This function will asks the user to input an integer, then inserts it to the linked list in ascending order. Will not insert if current value already existed.

```
typedef struct _listnode{
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode;         

typedef struct _linkedlist{
    int size;
    ListNode *head;
} LinkedList;           

void insertSortedLinkedList(LinkedList *l)
{
    ListNode *cur = l->head;
    ListNode* newNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); // create the node to be inserted
    int x;
    printf("please input an integer you want to add to the linked list:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    newNode->item = x;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (l->head == NULL) // linkedlist is empty, inserting as first element
    {
        l->head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        l->head->item = x;
        l->head->next = NULL;
        l->size++;
    }
    else
    {

        if (x < l->head->item) // data is smaller than first element, we will insert at first element and update head.
        {
            newNode->next = l->head;
            l->head = newNode;
            l->size++;
            return;
        }
        while (cur->next != NULL) // loop through the linkedlist
        {
            if (cur->next->item > x) // next element is bigger than data, we will insert it now.
            {
                if (cur->item != x) // if current element is not same as data, it must not have already existed.
                {
                    newNode->next = cur->next;
                    cur->next = newNode;
                    l->size++;
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (cur->next == NULL) // we have reached the last element and data is even greater than that. we will then insert it as last element.
            {
                cur->next = newNode;
                l->size++;
                return;
            }
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow, there's a bug in it. When I try to insert the following, I get these result. It also doesn't insert if the data is bigger than those existed.

```
Insert : 10
Result : 10
Insert : 5
Result : 5 10
Insert : 8
Result : 5 8 10
Insert : 10
Result : 5 8 10
Insert : 7
Result : 5 7 8 10
Insert : 9
Result : 5 7 8 9 10
Insert : 6 
Result : 5 6 7 8 9 10
Insert : 5
Result : 5 6 5 7 8 9 10 << why?
```

Comment: What did you find out when you were debugging?

Comment: The problem is in `if (cur->item != x) ` . When you are on node `6` it checks if `7` is greater than `5`. Yes..  Then it checks if `5!=6`.. true.. so it inserts it there

Comment: @user7 I don't get how would the current node ever reach node 6 if my list already has 5 6 7 8 9 10 and I wanted to insert 5. It would have detected that node 6(cur->next) is greater than 5 and then check if 5!=5 and thus exited the function

Comment: @MaTaKazer The return is inside the `if` block. How can it exit the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You test for equality in the wrong place: you always skip the first node.  You also need to improve the allocation scheme: you allocate memory twice for the head node and forget to free memory if the integer is already in the list.

Here is an improved version:

```
void insertSortedLinkedList(LinkedList *l)
{
    ListNode *cur, *newNode;
    int x;

    printf("please input an integer you want to add to the linked list:");
    if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1)
        return;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); // create the node to be inserted
    newNode->item = x;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (l->head == NULL)
    {
        // linkedlist is empty, inserting as first element
        l->head = newNode;
        l->size++;
        return;
    }
    if (x < l->head->item)
    {
        // data is smaller than first element, we will insert at first element and update head.
        newNode->next = l->head;
        l->head = newNode;
        l->size++;
        return;
    }
    for (cur = l->head;; cur = cur->next) // loop through the linkedlist
    {
        if (cur->item == x)
        {
            // element already in the list
            free(newNode);
            return;
        }
        if (!cur->next || cur->next->item > x)
        {
            // next element is bigger than data or end of list, we will insert it now.
            newNode->next = cur->next;
            cur->next = newNode;
            l->size++;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This code can be made shorter using a pointer to the link:

```
void insertSortedLinkedList(LinkedList *l)
{
    ListNode **curp, *cur, *newNode;
    int x;

    printf("please input an integer you want to add to the linked list:");
    if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1)
        return;

    for (curp = &l->head; (cur = *curp) != NULL; curp = &cur->next) {
        if (cur->item == x)
            return;
        if (cur->item > x)
            break;
    }
    // cur element is bigger than data or end of list, we will insert it now.
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); // create the node to be inserted
    newNode->item = x;
    newNode->next = cur;
    *curp = newNode;
    l->size++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you never reach your if-condition because when `cur->next == NULL` your loop breaks:

```
while (cur->next != NULL) // loop through the linkedlist
    ....
        if (cur->next == NULL) // we have reached the last element and data is even greater than that. we will then insert it as last element.
        {
           ...
        }
    ...
    }
```

Instead, you should have used `while(cur != NULL)` as loop, and set `cur->next == NULL` as first if-condition, so that `(cur->next->item` doesn't crash your program when `cur == NULL`.

NOTE: in this case, your loop condition won't be important because `return` in `if (cur->next == NULL)` will be breaking the loop. It's only important not to quit loop before you get to execute that `if`-condition.